# Significance of Message Size on RTT: Simple Java Server/Client Socket program

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, server, client

I have a simple Java Server/Client TCP Socket program that calculates the rtt. The way I did it was I let the client time-stamp its outgoing message, then the server adds a time-stamp when it receives the message and finally when the message is returned to the client it adds another time-stamp.

Well, the result I ended up with is kind of weird. I made a plot of the message size vs round-trip time and ended up with a straight line rather than a linear increase.

[image]

Can someone explain why that happened?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't think you need to timestamp the message on the server side. You just need the sending time to be added when you send the packet and then you can calculate the difference with the current time when the response get's back to the client (of course the server needs to copy the sent_time in the reply).

note: *If your server takes "long" time to execute then you will need to add some kind of "time to process" information to the packet by the server.*

```
RTT = (cur_clientTime_when_response_is_received - time_sent) - time_to_server_process
```

This formula has the advantage that doesn't care about time differences between the client and the server clock.

The straight line is explainable because the difference in time to send the data is not statistically relevant to overcome the randomness introduced in the network layer as it's **not** a real time media, and because it's shared with other application and hosts, if you are on a network switch.
Anyway, don't bother increasing the number of letters, the underlaying protocol will take a max of [MTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) (that usually is 1500) bytes per TCP packet: still not enough.